# String to PDF white page, Encoding /Identity-H

Tags: pdf, encoding, character-encoding, pdfbox

I have a database which contains a table with the following fields

- id
- data
- timestamp
- client_id

This was part of a very old web application that is no longer in use however is still been hosted in case we want to go back to to double check info. The field data currently is a string representing a file (xml, html and pdf). When the record is a pdf, I am trying to get the string
to open as pdf. I have done:

- copy the string into notepad and save it as pdf. This open the file and matches the number of pages, but the pages looks blank.
- I used a website like https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode the data as base64 and then I use a website like https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file to download the file, this does exactly the same as just saving the file as pdf where the downloaded file opens and display the same number of page but all of them are blank.

I am wonder what could i be missing to make this pdf to show their content?

In the ideal world I would like to run an script locally to generate this files and then uploaded them to S3 bucket, as we want to stop the server where this web application live

Table structure in mysql
[image]

[image: Sample of the record]

Sample String:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿC2B2-3DA7-9410-24DF::BF25-177E)
/Creator (þÿwkhtmltopdf 0.12.1)
/Producer (þÿQt 4.8.6)
/CreationDate (D:20150814130713+10'00')
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/SM 0.02
/ca 1.0
/CA 1.0
/AIS false
/SMask /None>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 594
/Height 72
/ImageMask true
/Decode [1 0]
/Length 7 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xœíÌ1
0ü›&vÒ
hÒ2µI¥R©T*•J¥R©T*•J¥R}©nZœ(ñ
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
48
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 594
/Height 72
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Mask 6 0 R
/Length 9 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xœíÕ1
€PA||)hÂ        t€äíLNÀu»öc™™™Mßvûý†™™ÙS=33ëì©Þ s©ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@‡êÐ¡zt¨ª@Ç«zÌsZ£Å
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
315
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 634
/Height 100
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Length 12 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xœuX    \SÇºŸoÎI"Ö-Å´O%D÷%„¢ ¸±/BØ!a_ÃHwq—MQ[ë­Ëµmmµ­µî·j«Õ.¶µÚÖwkûêmõ¾[Iï›$PÛþ^Îo`æœ93ß|ßþßBÈ ÒD8B¢â¦Í|>äèV¼ÓŠ%3¯¸.·%hÉ5¬? d¤%_Ÿ¥Óo[xŒÙwxÏ7ou—¸ââ†íñù%UÆ'’çŽb{>¶—åduÙºŸ¹¶ëK²Œåd^DÞƒm·Ò¬½4mÊ"l_'\   ÇWÀd""D´C¤Â;ãìÿ¹I.ÅX±ÿ¾"ƒû¢‰¢«
ÖŠ
'Á„ôYÅD $W²ƒ7{Ø3>@Ôƒ
7|]Dt8š7¶9"!ÏáäY@!UpRÀâ¬Àÿ à¼­ô¼¯ð?ð¬õySN„>|F­VQÏ“}"‰µÁjæ{{¥ÔHkŸÜ§éÖ½ô[šÎŒ‹s~sHÈ`\ƒ‚S‚
” î²µ¨½™zUS¯&Ëº@¸
B>ŽM…]IzßÜ{|$ñ"Äc¦ÆW­)KÄ^b/OµÚGã«ñUÍ”»È•>^žJw‰X&)w¡SªüÒ3Š?17øùçl8V] •ñ  û’µÚä˜ðÐŠœ˜¸)ÓÚ¶õŽÞT??¤°èpcdduõMåõÊ*fqrßÞ
ç•‘ „8{Ì$³Í¯tÇùå8—ŠÙ¤ÆÙñÂû2-Ì   ,+ÙpkÕJœSRºáÖÊÕF}Î¾½zÝÔi±ñ…/èôtJwƒ9<´£óÉ¨ÝæÆùí½NgÍ

æ«rS~ž¿ÀÜx™­¼W~™ R\¹Ø‹M(UI©ÊMƒÿ”\BÉOG´Úè.ÌX½v7èuè»Ö(áÊ§ÜðÞ‹ø~7Æõ
®@ŽƒÉ˜ù.r™T)eÆ¢«$X…³SRÊŽ$&ÔÎYQ–°Ô»–8©Sû@Vöyk½´%<BÃ«­Ï¡8¢¼ï
EÙF”ªdJ)s€‹Ffw‡T©VI!ñ«¯ncçO‹®×ø]º$Š~Ì¶NK™4žÉ–.k¥7²A†c@DüŒˆxÑ¦”*ÐþUñ?›-ïšL\°™¾i
õX
t#ö>„3º‹    Û‘Ø[îF£˜E©}tkR†0g†9sZ¬D„8;"$µa£¸¢ììçUµ•Uwß6TA]\lçíô´/:ãâ©—¥};Àašñ„lÞm’ë5Æs`¹YSëÀ÷1zr,ñÆ}èÎ‚­VÛ ¡a>•)db;4r10×*"hÐº²ŠÙsÅÅËÎWWZ,P”ÿBæ¢…‹W
ÿZ–îLWÅ'Œœb2vNBL,X¹æ»ùÉ:“Ò=Òÿ4gÉÑ½4´;;‹Ø£I· 
Ã±á©Ûã§’1PÒ-ž“*""µ5é7fŒå>’Àìàë(>àð»CÑúÆ¾ÿÀd^ƒoŽ#DããÀ±ÄÎj7Êe¼å..rï   29ýcsûhW×ÑîJ¹Ü…{ç©qDtFÔ‰íp4N!c,ò¹5ÙÄ­²<¦ûék’¨§Àzû¾ˆ»k/öµ!i`G1d;ö”FÊï
ž[UÓ~}+
^{­ D=–±ÛJJýg-3ßå~´xÔåææ¾Î}Þ?û#ûì
%0ß DùG&Ë[f3VÏßéuõô*ø»è‘}}ü)ì;œ<GÂŽ­ÃhgÀ¶ÆWªÆ +O@Ç±M££¢¢7n~Sø   Fþ³u=¬YwWÔ×ÑufÕ¹ŽÎ˜8…õºwu€¨éIgZÒ‚k;-:O<Ð,ÇÂþDVÔAâ<þôèõ­÷÷™–…ÌŸÒ¼lÿ÷kWÉÍÓ„î‹ÕµU†sg²³\áâýºú˜˜¶í§Oéh‹‹YÖt°½M°³´·§¥¼Épjîû‘ÿg–3ÎûrXŒŸšÛE&¡vªr–°Ï/å
oj>Ð×½ÂÃš›hj
«ƒšÚkWŒõ`4~p½¦š®½ÜÑoMûÅ]q±11ÛÛÎŽ1Û:ÛÛ…G‚¥½CÑ«ÐÃÃ°€R*E¾—2ÊI¡£èsûj¬÷3¬ß× Ó÷ŠDÈöõtÝßgm´.Ç×ñœgçD“
K6<Ý¶.å†[j¸•–ÓƒÈGò¦¾ÀÕÇ7ÞÂ7F°¨Úˆë•37€“25ª‚Þ’ÍðÙw+–ClÜZ(n±üu;2Ò‘õŽ
ciKÔå†Ë
‹½­mCé%HNjíJL@«nâÈ‘¶\iç¡H“  [vk9¬ažö`vªÀ‡^³7çç³ÕPÛó­XbGüï¦yyØìbéK*<üfårXÖô³°ªe¤§eü]h¡1ÖWÐ¢ÊêË”V@>$&tµkµ8+*~»-«:Ö«VðÛ…¡&aŸ)
rR^€½\±×ì5ˆÅBÅ&ÍS­¿˜¬¿n¥íÜhK•õ6Ïµbïpäº7°·3öVIûSª?Õq
Pc|ï#ƒÁ×¹.  w´®™Le¥ÿØš²‡Ån)â°q¨Á†=5zjìÜÌhËÕ,WŽ”»Ø/›Flë¦rl
îaBâ×÷òÚ`ÝšO7W‚‚Ì¹¹‡÷çä$']8¯×ù¨p~½³±yÞ|0AUåéƒùy[:7hqÁË/æhütúúí©ZX¸ØXîãë?+*ºäå¼|ðÓää4íLJ^¼ˆEf;Ú€¶rlÅ,¦œ§ƒÖGÚ×ÎrÍ»xz¸º¸¸zxºÈùðwwe¤èú;û±lû
f"5K5èlý®µFcìîÔðë&ªX!äˆ‰eB=t~ÖÌ‚ôø%dv‚ºNá©î'Cæ1•
±È¨p°9“eð‘r™bF£¶    t".ÎÊ.Ù•™
+–?øÂ®iÀ­j4{^+(P
ƒŒi“?yM§Ÿ2S7iÊÒÄU»ÒRÀT9^ðÜäf¾6õìŽ’³ü³
*O  Ä5µã.nBË<û„›œýå¥v¡t¨ˆ§Å3Zm°€ìÌZH«ž=gýò¤äÁuÁóVVÄÄxù€ž¬™3nèü|AXiJÿ±9<,6¶ÚêCo¬
à¹ÖÑLkp6ŽFz@5:–±™¥mÝ¿sìD­±mõï»èù¾¾nvPacä07Ü¶CÅ®ôHJîVBtWbüÒäá}QOfö[†Øøñc2³—-*ú¶õpLÔæUÑ‘ùºjÃ¼ô€õE7z@Í²®—ãR;°,PH–;(×Žc´‰a6oŽŠñð**<p¼´Ä]W¶ 0`Owt¤§@IÙ±SHô&ˆ‹]½,"œ“4j·1¼üýcb’´›Óƒƒ|Ôñ±“¦xxN˜0+~-F75¥µ `‚­ÄøpGÑm?›°VÁO°Ð$g    …¦¿qm½íú-ÕË¬¢Â÷3xÊ5Î¬»—ÄöÎžg]Ïø/ù³p!WøaèPáç\á¢é·´l.ÐrÅPÀÍé½ÈigZöã(…‰“2NëCÄƒ
œÒRJ_~JaÖr-Y¨0ÿ"1mzn'æNÎ¦çÜìw‚Œm&›z•öËl‰ÔF<W^ñÎ½*C­á«ÓeFdóŽª¨oío¥Ï
ÛÚlë®£°e›ÐË}‚gÐø—®W««Ñz<³Ñ×EÇ™×pß‹Ô*úºQ¨‚‡#EnÛÊO 5FŒþcä)Q¢5Ô~ìp–Ž°/U*ñ±[#—°ãc(¯¸}«²
_Þ2jcâöíÅ`ÅÇïÝK3„«{^ØÝ
“@ªÝ»:º„OÅOšQõ7<¾ùmÅŠææßX¬²qîG87’ÞmÊtÞ¿~'P5žÆ±/¼”°Íœ±d¢wTô¶
IZ£¿¿^g¾h0Ì›_¹ý^Wµ¥¨4 ÐÙY;’ -ã¸‘…úrnPÜúè¨Ø¸Õåi*UqÉ[IÚI^)éoW@­ÊHmhML†èÈÎ-¸ÉÐSÍÈøƒD'É2•q…ÒM"–öÛ(î×!j5Õøzp²~™‡&s‹‡ ÿîèœ•šjx§¢|Ô997–·À«Ç ü‹Ê¬EvV÷z4–ŠNæuíÆN›²bÕÇ›*As¡³ã_FXýé'`í ÍË=]k,+=t8?ù03ß`ä1Ë|¨0=¶nm …–óÜ)QÑ“6Ñ¢\†:]ßcîúz™n×l^âœe#]ÔJ±Ï7<.€™Íh™a\ŽÞæÊƒÓ3KÌé*5øùê³[¾¨¯ƒ„ý.A²v°ß˜™>RÒvmÒ¦$/¥{3fªæW”¯ÞT[3/pM÷‹…êaëæóÂ*Cï˜êÀPõòþ²
¶Ž\Ç(´ÏÌÕàÀ‚×@Zø àGYÊáWóôé11·á„µ~¾ù¹-—åAs÷…ÔšJ}7¦§&¯‹‰‚ôŒ6“^7Ë¿ àxn]ýk#9r#é‚>ç)g”2Ü@2´9…mCÔ|NoY7©ªvŸ¯©6®®®Q9"!~SwtRîŽÄ9Aaôz±LÐØôñ·ME…§Û–Dää¼ñ¼^2ùlœwl_ýÁ®¬äHFëKhfqƒx
F'W¿Ÿ¶©IvìdJùJ!•pù÷î­qto‹µ”ŽVÃÇza3”Ïç,.8•å‘\“#¶ÁUÜŸÝqAO;5ŽôÊ=%NØ¶SsÊ‘÷ú½yóŠ"–46]ÿ¨—²hASqð\¨®<sº¶:6+»½3#3-mÊIOHHZ¹6. 1~íêÄÞß¤89#sÙÛÅ¥PZò¶);sòDm’áxQ!—XÚW'/…„Äõ­x¤ˆ‹m¥'ÍŒþ£b—7EFBtúh½0‘–ˆ3™¾u¶cSnÛ\HbËO­~š’¢†1!ÁsUªqnÓ§ÆÇêÇ4ûúÑ%Ÿ]{ÿïÇLÓjÍ
];ÏxæìÖ¶…K¼ÊNenÂb®ÇñÅýkc_µœá%‹_!°Y˜ášüæäés–úùzª…ü–ÃÜÆÞa~†åˆ'O,ÚÊÏ`R •­Õ‘xùöó^vH©¯_aQó˜¬„ØÓ§OOÌ³¬¨Ð_CgyùêÁCaÛ¶^8ûígßíìˆ8xèýŒËXÆa§|•Ú.Ö$v$cÒû—W_…Ä¸Î@'U@ŽÆ€
w+»å¥ä$€º!³ƒÊWe[¼Ùh3h4A3Ì1r #Ü¥ÑzÆ  ÅB÷fþqŒÑl§d¹Z%uˆB\…ýËØ¾3x9¾4”Ÿû²ª²ºæREn~@Hã+ññ•_œ*7Ø>:¤MŒŠ.µ}v°âqé•îÞÛ7êêU3t'/Ý½æhoï]¯1^„ÿÍóó­©eYQÈä)Ú"%îYÑ~úg•z90‹Y¹1ÊÓòŠ·îÔÔªïž++3&$v”FEO˜UÚžoKŒÝÖ[¢Ï»Ã6LŒü5£||uÖßÒfÌ¨¯EÏTöMç¬â
Äÿ)Ï\­VÉú…ís—x@Â³HË”j±#Ù¶ÊÊßc¤§Ïy9÷T„1q­›"£aÑÂžW¢#'xåæÓ_.)5BªvßFmä•…‡…ådí|1W7üòeieÕ%&TQÂ›!¡¾~—äíÓå}çŠþ÷º“’!b    Z»¥ï?ˆjdø_¿olùÿ?`0ØŠèùµ¡Ã³¾ý    ÅMè `YÄñÃw$Å*}§}ª>•¸É6ÒÓ¿@<Kéø>2–GÒyÑòzÒ…¥›n%røç<HNÀrˆ7bÞhéQÒ
GH#ßDNˆæ‘}¢#ø6–™¤ETHÄÈ  ~¶G’ãTAnòlÿ„åñá/W>„ó§HŽÙÆýHºù…D'‘“vþ>öJôÜgÄS<ˆñ:|VFvb9†¥K6–åX"°è±`9ÀMAÛËH–Bº´rï7º“(èK$ˆ."3ør´Û>N%|O¶àšg’(²ž\%@³ðŠ…tØ7á!Oh­£è?¹‰ÜbNÇµs{¹cÜ—ÜC^ÂOàùùwECE‹EE_‹‹ÇˆÃÄfññ‰»¤DÒ,ùpdPÈ èAeƒ>v9y;%:58­wúpðàÁYƒ—ÙãAÉ\vúv´þü“-îràìçaGbFquÔ¹§îóOÕEd2êk{]Œ÷cõa$žbý‡¥
‹Y‚™:äc+–è±VMŠI1DlH%>-#¥Øo&rÊt¼fà¥Æ2Ëvµ}þ0â”§Fd¥Š”£œ†W­íšŠ£—cÉÁ§zl•á,yø´ßÊÁ;¥8§Ë4g!æÑPIâðï»ÿC%˜ð
endstream
endobj
36 0 obj
4859
endobj
34 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /Roboto-Light
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >>
/FontDescriptor 32 0 R
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/W [0 [440 620 511 556 545 545 319 241 702 222 551 512 334 208 558 652 704 650 644 671 858 564 630 264 523 611 592 594 546 588 222 486 531 879 608 502 477 748 544 550 550 550 550 550 550 550 550 550 394 550 550 316 471 323 328 284 550 550 550 237 ]
]
>>
endobj
35 0 obj
<< /Length 777 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
2 beginbfrange
<0000> <0000> <0000>
<0001> <003B> [<0041> <0063> <006F> <0075> <006E> <0074> <0020> <0048> <006C> <0064> <0065> <0072> <003A> <0046> <0055> <004E> <0044> <0043> <004F> <004D> <0045> <0052> <0049> <004C> <0050> <0054> <0059> <004A> <0053> <0069> <006B> <0061> <006D> <0042> <0073> <0076> <0077> <0068> <0062> <0031> <0030> <0033> <0036> <0037> <0039> <0032> <0035> <002F> <0034> <0038> <0028> <0079> <0029> <0066> <002D> <0067> <0070> <0024> <002E> ]
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream
endobj
10 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /Roboto-Light
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [34 0 R]
/ToUnicode 35 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids 
[
5 0 R
]
/Count 1
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC]
>>
endobj
xref
0 37
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000023948 00000 n 
0000000223 00000 n 
0000000318 00000 n 
0000008502 00000 n 
0000000355 00000 n 
0000000560 00000 n 
0000000578 00000 n 
0000001075 00000 n 
0000023809 00000 n 
0000001094 00000 n 
0000004216 00000 n 
0000004237 00000 n 
0000008431 00000 n 
0000017155 00000 n 
0000013032 00000 n 
0000008452 00000 n 
0000008859 00000 n 
0000010796 00000 n 
0000008623 00000 n 
0000008839 00000 n 
0000010817 00000 n 
0000011026 00000 n 
0000012309 00000 n 
0000012560 00000 n 
0000012288 00000 n 
0000013174 00000 n 
0000013437 00000 n 
0000016203 00000 n 
0000016536 00000 n 
0000016182 00000 n 
0000017295 00000 n 
0000017557 00000 n 
0000022528 00000 n 
0000022980 00000 n 
0000022507 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 37
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 17 0 R
>>
startxref
24046
%%EOF
```

Comment: You need the save this as binary data, not as a string.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have added a screenshot of the field in the table structure of the database. Could you please explain me how to save it as binary data

Comment: @KJ Yeah unfortnately I was ask as that pdf contains sensitive data, so I paste a portion of the file that is probably why it shows 11kb instead of 23kb, but yeah that sample belongs to a file that is 1 page. Why I dont know is how can I transform that string into a binary, I used this online tool https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-binary.html but not sure if this is what you are refering to and once this binary string how can i convert it into a file

Comment: If the file was saved as base64 then it is OK but you need to save it as binary when decoding, not as string. Please include the code you're using.

Comment: Do you still have the code that stored the files in the database? And the database connection parameters of that old program?

Comment: @KJI dont think the file is corrupted as from the web app I can still see the PDF, the problem is that I cant add the whole string in here for confidentiality, I am trying to look for one that I could show but so far everything has confidential informationm, I just add another image to show you how it is currently in the database

Comment: @TilmanHausherrI have added an extra image just above the pdf string in the question, of how it is store in the Database

Comment: That looks bad. Your text here is somewhat contradictory, at one place you mention base64, at another place you mention it is stored as a string. The thing I see in the image is a very bad idea. PDFs are (almost always) binary data so it should not be stored as a string.

Comment: Indeed, handling binary data as text always has a good chance of damaging the data.  Furthermore, you have to make sure you use the same encoding to turn the binary into string as to turn the string back into a usable binary. You say you can see the pdf in the web application. So let's assume the data is not damaged. Thus, to get back the binary pdf file, you have to retrieve the string and store it to file using the same encoding settings as the web application has used.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am sorry for any confusion, what you see in the picture is what I got handed, in my localmachine, I would have done things very different IE: file in s3 bucket table with the link or something like that. Unfortunately that is what I got, I want to try to retriev those pdf files, I run a ptyhon script as some files are html and xml, and i was able to create them with no problem, but unfortunately most of the files are PDF, and I dont know how to transform them into an actual PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get access to sftp.

I run the below script and use filezilla to download the files.

Because the files where named after their ID's, we are able to link to the actual parent record

```
<?php
    $db_con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_pass","my_database");
    if ($db_con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db_con->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, data, app_id FROM my_table WHERE SUBSTRING(data, 1, 4) = '%PDF'";
    $result = $db_con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $fname = $row['id'].'-'.$row['app_id'].".pdf";
            $myfile = fopen('pdf/'.$fname, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = $row['data'];
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $db_con->close();
?>
```